# Add hover effect to a picture

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**Hello Everyone!**

I am designing a website for myself and I am making this sick front page but I need to know how to make it work.

From this when it's normal:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM0c0.png (Copy and paste in a different browser, I cannot post direct images)

And this would be how it'd look when you hover over it, the background would fade black and the image would pop out with a bigger size:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsvmu.png

Anyone knows how to do this?

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make 2 divs

**'Div1 Small Button'** and
**'Div2 Big Button'**

Then you will need to make them showing and hiding with jQuery.
And make it like: if hover that button then show Div2 Big Button else hide.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it with pure CSS. Best way is to use the `:hover` property.

HTML:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsvmu.png"/>
```

CSS:

```
 img{
    height:200px; 
    width:200px;
}
img:hover{
    width:400px; /*OR transform: scale(1.5)*/
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4r2s0eto/). Hover over the image to see the effect.

Also if you want the background to be colored as in your image then wrap the image inside a `div`. And use the following css:

```
 <div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsvmu.png"/></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {  
    pointer-events: none;
}

img {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

div:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
img{
    height:200px; 
    width:200px;
}
img:hover{
    width:400px; /*OR transform: scale(1.5)*/
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

Upadated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r2s0eto/2/).

Comment: Amazing, any way it can fade so it looks pretty neat?

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4r2s0eto/4/)?

Comment: Yeah but maybe a bit faster?

Comment: @St3fanNL The second field to `transition` is duration, which is 1second(1s) now. Change it to `500ms` or whatever you feel like,

Comment: Alright, I tried it but its not really what im looking for.
Im looking for a kind of Modal effect, blending the background and replace the image with another (bigger and less blue)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use transform css property to resize the same image when user hover on it.

```
.banner img:hover {

   transform: scale(1.25);

 }
```